# laravel vagrant/homestead fails to install. git bash error

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDYw4.png)
laravel homestead fails to install vagrant
git bash error
git bash codes don't work
windows 10 vagrant install test

**problem:**
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/childprocess-4.0.0/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:44:in `encode!': "\xC4" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to UTF-16LE (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError) from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/childprocess-4.0.0/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:44:in` to_wide_string'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/childprocess-4.0.0/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:67:in `create_environment_pointer' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/childprocess-4.0.0/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:28:in` start'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/childprocess-4.0.0/lib/childprocess/windows/process.rb:70:in `launch_process' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/childprocess-4.0.0/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:81:in` start'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:155:in `block in execute' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:26:in` block (2 levels) in safe_chdir'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:25:in `chdir' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:25:in` block in safe_chdir'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:24:in `synchronize' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:24:in` safe_chdir'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:154:in `execute' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:22:in` execute'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/powershell.rb:174:in `version' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/powershell.rb:195:in` validate_install!'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/powershell.rb:96:in `execute_cmd' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:82:in` block in windows_admin?'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:84:in `windows_admin?' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/plugins/providers/hyperv/provider.rb:20:in` usable?'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:361:in `block in default_provider' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:49:in` block in each'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:48:in `each' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:48:in` each'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:347:in `default_provider' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:943:in` guess_provider'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:955:in `find_configured_plugins' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:983:in` process_configured_plugins'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:178:in `initialize' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/bin/vagrant:168:in` new'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/bin/vagrant:168:in `'

Answer (score 0):

You should go to "C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\2.2.14\gems\vagrant-2.2.14\bin" address and open "vagrant" file. At the beginning of the file, you will see "#!/usr/bin/env ruby" Paste the below 2 lines after this first line.

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding.find('Windows-1251')
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.find('Windows-1251')
```

Be careful, they are "1251", not "1250".